# Personal wiki-hosting with LaTeX-like equations

Tags: gratis, web-apps, collaboration, wiki, latex

I really like how Wikipedia works. But you cannot write *original research* nor *beletry* on Wikipedia :-( … nor use it as you personal blog ;-) So I would like to find some **wiki-hosting as similar to Wikipedia as possible**.

I know there is quite a lot of [wiki hostings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_hosting_services), I tried a few (namely Wikispaces, Wikia, and Wikidot) but I was not satisfied. None of them provide all **features which I want**:

- LaTeX-like syntax for writing math equations.
- Preferably standard [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) syntax and interface. I'm used to it from Wikipedia but it is not absolutely necessary.
- Page editing can be restricted just to some users (e.g. me and my friends).
- Not too much limited space for images (at least like 100 MB?).
- Free of charge.

**What I want to use it for?**

I'm a physicist and sci-fi fan. I often dream about some scientific concepts which are too frivolous and flippant to produce a scientific publication, but it is also not really a story to write a sci-fi novel. I find the wiki format ideal for noting down such ideas, to collaborate on it with friends, and to present it to others. Because I'm a physicist, even though the ideas are frivolous, I would still prefer to use maths (LaTeX equations) for the description of some aspects.

---

**EDIT** - currentrly I'm using [wikidot](http://www.wikidot.com/), it is not MediaWiki, but syntax is easy, it has LaTeX math equation and otherwise quite pleasing.

Comment: Is it okay if the equations have to be inserted as images? (such images can be generated from latex using a tool like [iTex2Img](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor))

Comment: if possible not, it is very quite inconvenient. But latex math support is not so rare by itself. eg. http://www.wikidot.com/doc-wiki-syntax:math

Comment: I was thinking of [Github wikis](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis), but I can't get MathJax to work with it. [Here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11255900/1836949) I was trying to follow. Maybe you'll have better luck. Post an answer if you do

Comment: [ShoutWiki](http://www.shoutwiki.com/) meets all your criteria. They have a fairly restrictive file size limit, but you can hotlink images from external hosting.

Comment: Thanks, I will check i out, currently I'm using wikidot. I will see if advantages of ShoutWiki are big enought to migrate.

Comment: Totally and utterly off-topic, but I have to tell you: This is the first time I've seen the word *beletry*. It's kind of hard to Google this from the U.S. Most attempts automatically translate it to either *fiction* or *novel*. So I am guessing it's a word of Slavic origin, and native Czech speakers (and perhaps other Europeans) seem not to realize that it's a highly unusual (if not completely nonstandard!) word in English. (Other than that word, I had no trouble understanding your English.)

Comment: its not slavic, it comes from latin "bella litera", but perhabs not so common in english

Answer (score 2):

I've recently (today) started using [**Tiddlywiki**](http://tiddlywiki.com/), and I'm considering moving some of my shorter notes there from Git because of its interesting format. I think it fits your requirements, particularly because you could either host it on your Dropbox or Drive accounts, or on their service, and edit it using any browser. <s>It's disadvantage, in my opinion, is that it doesn't have version control. So the user has to perform regular backups.</s>(*)

Features:

- LaTeX-like syntax for math equations through the [KaTeX plug-in](http://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/katex/)
- Uses [WikiTex markup](http://tiddlywiki.com/static/WikiText.html). It also has a [plug-in for Markdown support](http://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/markdown/)
- Page editing is restricted to yourself, but you could add collaborators by creating a shared Dropbox folder, for example. There is also the option of hosting the wiki on [TiddlySpot](http://tiddlyspot.com/), which stores it using an unencrypted password that you could then share with your friends.
- The space for image storage would be limited to the space in your Dropbox or Drive accounts. Or you could use an image hosting service, like [imgur](https://imgur.com/), [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/), or [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) and link the images from there.
- It's free of charge

Although it's different than the traditional wiki style, I believe the "tiddlers" format it utilizes is good for short notes and to keep track of brain droppings.

---

(*) **Edit:**

The desktop app [TiddlyDesktop](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyDesktop/releases) does automatic backups. Quote:

> Backups
>
> Backups are automatically made every time saving changes results in a file being overwritten. The previous content of the file is copied to a backup file with a filename such as `\MyData\index.html_backup\index.20150107172517000.html`.
>
> The path of the backup file can be an absolute path or a relative path to the directory containing the TiddlyWiki file. The backup path can contain the following special tokens:
>
> `$filename$` to stand for the filename portion of the URL of the TiddlyWiki file
>
> `$filepath$` to stand for the entire filepath of the URL of the TiddlyWiki file

Comment: hmm, it seems I cannot save anything